# SQLite format number with 2 decimal places always

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have some tables in a SQLite database that contains FLOAT column type, now i want to retrieve the value with a Query and format the float field always with 2 decimal places, so far i have written i query like this one :

```
SELECT ROUND(floatField,2) AS field FROM table
```

this return a resultset like the the following :

```
3.56
----
2.4
----
4.78
----
3
```

I want to format the result always with two decimal places, so :

```
3.56
----
2.40
----
4.78
----
3.00
```

Is it possible to format always with 2 decimal places directly from the SQL Query ? How can it be done in SQLite ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 88):

You can use [`printf`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#printf) as:

```
SELECT printf("%.2f", floatField) AS field FROM table;
```

for example:

```
sqlite> SELECT printf("%.2f", floatField) AS field FROM mytable;
3.56
2.40
4.78
3.00
sqlite>
```

Comment: Only available with SQLite 3.8.3 or greater (Feb 2014 release)

Comment: Like @swdev stated, this function is now available in many Android devices out there, which might potentially cause app crashes on unsupported devices. I discovered thi by experience, testing on an GAlaxy SIII w/o the latest updates (which is quite common, BTW).

Comment: Same problem here, I need to support some older devices and I can't use printf

Comment: As a side mark, thousands separator (comma only supported) cannot be used along with decimals and work only for integers, format is `select printf ('%,d',4115.782)` (https://www.sqlite.org/printf.html)

Comment: Leading zeros can be added e.g. for minimum 10 symbols length`select printf ('%010.2f',4115.782);`

Comment: Also to note that the result is not a number anymore, for example ordering by it will use string ordering

Comment: I'm using QGIS&Spatialite and double quotes did not work for me. Changing to single quotes like in Alexei's comments made it work.

Comment: You should be using single quotes for strings: `'%2.f'`. Double quotes obviously will work, but don’t follow the ANSI standard, and were only included to be compatible with MySQL practices, regretted, and left in for backwards compatibility.

Comment: this works with `csvsql`'s default options too, thank goodness. I had a nightmare googling for it.

Answer (score 2):

On older versions of SQLite that don't have `PRINTF` available you can use `ROUND`.

For example...

```
SELECT 
   ROUND(time_in_secs/1000.0/60.0, 2) || " mins" AS time,
   ROUND(thing_count/100.0, 2) || " %" AS percent
FROM
   blah
```

Comment: The question already mentions `ROUND`, this answer doesn't bring anything new.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the way sqlite stores numbers internally,

You probably want something like this

```
select case when substr(num,length(ROUND(floatField,2))-1,1) = "." then num || "0" else num end from table;
```

Comment: Doesn't work, the number could also be above 10, so i could have 100.4, 1290.7, ...

Comment: Exponent notation will make this fail, too.

Answer (score -2):

u can solve it like this:

```
SELECT round(-4.535,2);
```

> -4.54

Comment: What about 2.4?