# ActiveRecord Sum is showing strange digits

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

.sum is displaying crazy digits that vary when I add or delete rows and I can't account for these digits as I type in the amount into that column. The column type is decimal.

This is my column:

[image: This is my column]

And this is the sum being displayed:

[image: This is the sum]

This is the amount column being displayed, I'm not converting it to a string.

```
<td><%= event.amount %></td>
```

This is the sum being displayed.

```
<td><%= @events.sum :amount %></td>
```

Comment: Which Database are you using?

Comment: Can you show the generated query?

Comment: sum query is SELECT SUM("events"."amount") AS sum_id FROM "events" WHERE "events"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 5]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As sqlite uses IEEE floating point numbers (see [sqlite data types](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)) decimal numbers are not perfectly represented.

The normal way to deal with it is, to round the result to i.e. two decimal places.

see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21956882/1065703):

In rails use round or view helper `number_with_precision`:

```
<td><%= event.amount.round(2) %></td>
```

or

```
<td><%= number_with_precision event.amount, precision: 2  %></td>
```

Comment: How does sqlite get away with this horrible offense? Am I the only one trying to store decimals in an sqlite database?

Comment: Horrible offense is just an opinion. There are good reasons for IEEE binary flaoting points (fast, hardware accelerated, standard) as well as for decimal numbers (mainly if you are dealing with monetary values or arbitrary precicions). Sqlite focuses on light footprint (embedded db), so it is reasonable to use the already there floating point arithmetics. It is not recommended for rails production systems.